# Non linear optimization Minizinc and Cplex

Tags: cplex, minizinc

I have a simple non linear code built in minizinc as follows.

```
array[1..3] of var 1..10:x;
array[1..3] of var 10.0..20.0:y;
var float:z;
constraint sum(i in 1..3)(x[i]*y[i])=z;
solve minimize z;
```

If I use Cplex solver in minizinc background I have an error of Float_times.

```
unable to create linear formulation for the `float_times` constraint. This model instance cannot be solved using a linear solver.
```

If I convert the same code to OPL and use them in IBM ILOG Cplex IDE It provide the answer.Sample code as follows.

```
dvar int x[ 1..3]  in 1..10;
dvar float y[ 1..3]  in 10.0..20.0;
dvar float z;
minimize z;
subject to {
cons1:
sum(i in 1..3)x[i]*y[i]==z;
}
```

Could you someone explain why it is happening even though I used the same solver in both backends.

Comment: What is the best solver that I can handle above minizinc code from minizinc IDE.

Comment: You can try with the CP solvers that support `float_times`, e.g. Gecode, JaCoP, or OptiMathSAT. I'm not sure which MIP-solvers support `float_times`. Apparently, CPLEX don't. Perhaps Gurobi?

Answer (score 2):

your constraint is not linear.
When you solve with OPL the presolve did everything but if you remove presolve then you need to change optimality target:

```
execute
{
  cplex.preind=0;
  cplex.optimalitytarget=3;
}

dvar int x[ 1..3]  in 1..10;
dvar float y[ 1..3]  in 10.0..20.0;
dvar float z;
minimize z;
subject to {
cons1:
sum(i in 1..3)x[i]*y[i]==z;
}
```

works fine

So you could either set that setting "optimality target" through minizinc

Or rely on logical constraints / indicators

```
execute
{
  cplex.preind=0;
  //cplex.optimalitytarget=3;
}

dvar int x[ 1..3]  in 1..10;
dvar float y[ 1..3]  in 10.0..20.0;
dvar float z;
dvar float xy[1..3];
minimize z;
subject to {
cons1:
sum(i in 1..3)xy[i]==z;

forall(i in 1..3) forall(j in 1..10) (x[i]==j) => xy[i]==y[i]*j;
}
```

works fine too